# RethinkDB multiple queries in a single request

Tags: ruby, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-ruby

I'm trying to execute several RQL commands in a single request to server, without much success I may add. I have tried `r.union`, but it only works with sequences. What I really want:

```
[r.db(..).table(..).get(id1).delete(),
 r.db(..).table(..).get(id2).delete(),
 r.db(..).table(..).insert(...)].run_all_at_once
```

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do

```
r.expr( [r.db(...).table(...).get(id1).delete(), 
r.db(...).table(...).get(id1).delete(), 
r.db(...).table(...).insert(...) ] ).run(conn)
```

Note that the method delete doesn't get an argument.

Comment: Yep, that works. I wouldn't have figured out from the description: http://rethinkdb.com/api/ruby/expr/

Comment: This is better than `r.do`, because it returns the results for all queries

Answer (score 11):

You can also use [do](http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/do/)

```
r.do(
  r.table('test').insert({value1: "Hey"}),
  r.table('test').insert({value2: "Ho"})
).run(conn);
```

- The queries are evaluated from last to first
- The response will be the last query's result

Comment: What if I wanted to get the generated key (UUID) that is returned by the first `insert`?